# How merge (git rebase) multiple commits in a remote branch in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase

I am asked to merge multiple commits in a remote branch in BitBucket.
[image]
The last two and first three commits are contributed by different people.

I have watched some YouTube videos, but still cannot figure out how to do this. Below is what I did:

Run this command in a local branch

> git rebase -i HEAD~5

[image]

And then

> git push  <local_branch>:<remote_name> -f

Once I push this, my pull request gets declined. If I try to re-open my pull request, I will see this error message:
[image]

Does anyone know how to combine a bunch of commits?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebasing your branch from the latest version of the remote branch? Looks like that's the reason for the rejection?

Comment: I run "git pull <remote> <branch>" before rebasing

Comment: in git, `pull` is equivalent to `fetch + rebase` or `fetch + merge` (default). In your case, I would suggest that you do a `git fetch`, followed by `git rebase`

Comment: OTOH, if you are looking to squash a bunch of commits, you can use the `git rebase -i <parent commit from where you want to squash>` - this could be an option